# Is there a better way to return and display multiple lists to a view in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp

I am interested in returning multiple lists to a view so I can eventually display rows of information from totally different queries on one page.  I have figured out how to do the following:

Here is my action in my controller:

```
 def processMultipleLists()
 {

    def stirList = []

    Person stirling = new Person('Stirling','Crow', 47)
    Person lady = new Person('Lady','McShavers', 4)

    stirList << stirling
    stirList << lady

    def kathieList = []

    Person kathie = new Person('Kathie','Esquibel', 47)
    Person milagro = new Person('Milagro','Muffin', 4)
    Person meeko = new Person('Meeko','Muffin', 4)

    kathieList << kathie
    kathieList << milagro
    kathieList << meeko

    def returnThisMap = [:]
    returnThisMap.put('One', kathieList)
    returnThisMap.put('Two', stirList)


    return [returnMap : returnThisMap]
}
```

Grails then returns the "returnMap" (that contains "returnThisMap", referred to below as "mapNum") to my view which has the following:

```
<g:if test="${returnMap.size() > 0}">

    <table border="1">

        <tbody>
          <g:each in="${returnMap}" status="i" var="mapNum">
            <g:if test="${mapNum.getKey() == 'One'}">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Favorite Number</th>

                </tr>

                <g:each in="${mapNum.getValue()}" status="c" var="listVar">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${listVar.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${listVar.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${listVar.favNumber}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>



            </g:if>
            <g:elseif test="${mapNum.getKey() == 'Two'}">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Favorite Number</th>

                </tr>

                <g:each in="${mapNum.getValue()}" status="c" var="listVar">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${listVar.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${listVar.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${listVar.favNumber}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </g:elseif>


          </g:each>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    No records were found to display.
</g:else>
```

This actually works.  It posts the info from both lists.  But... it feels a bit "hacky" since I have to use a groovy tag to iterate over the key/pair values in the returnMap.  Is there a better way to display multiple lists in Grails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object being returned to your view is already a map, so there's no need to create another map. You can do this:

```
return [stirList: stirList, kathieList: kathieList]
```

Then in your view you can iterate over each of them separately:

```
<g:each in="${stirList}" var="stir">
    ...
</g:each>
<g:each in="${kathieList}" var="kathie">
    ...
</g:each>
```

In your example, it looks like both lists contain the same type and are displayed exactly the same way, so a distinction might not even be necessary.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!! This is so much better than how I was doing it.